# How to run normal program in mpich clusters?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mpi, mpich, supercomputers

I'm making a cluster network(kind of super computer, but 'super fast') with my ubuntu installed computers, to run mprime of [GIMPS Project](http://www.mersenne.org/). I used [this tutorial](http://davebennett.tech/how-to-build-a-supercomputer/). However, I don't know how to run mprime in my clusters.

`mpi exec -n 4 -f /home/user1/mpi/hosts ./mprime`

This code worked, but I'm not sure that mprime will use every nodes and work quickly by executing this code. Maybe it's just using one node, isn't it? Because it looks like mprime is not made for mpich.

Please tell me if there is some solution.

Comment: While you technically can (ab)use `mpiexec` to run non-mpi programs, this is neither guaranteed to work, nor will you get any support regarding the work sharing. I would suppose there are better ways to run GIMPs on a cluster.

Comment: Thanks. I will try some other solutions.